# beautifulsoup python how to loop through cells in a table and find <a>links</a>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(html))
table = soup.find("table")
firstRow = table.contents[0]

for tr in firstRow:
  if 'Total' in tr:
    text = ''.join(tr.find(text=True))
    print(text)
```

Sometimes the table element contains a link with the text instead of plain text. In that case the above for loop loops through all cells and doesn't find the text 'Total', because it's in
    `<a title="err">Total</a>`
instead.
How can I modify my loop to find the text in the link if there is a link?

Answer (score 1):

Calling your iteration variable `tr` is misleading. You're iterating *over* a table row; the individual items are `td` or `th` elements, or just cells. Not a table row.

Looking at the Beautiful Soup documentation, it looks like you want the `string` property:

> If a tag has only one child, and that child is a NavigableString, the child is made available as .string ... **If a tag’s only child is another tag, and that tag has a .string, then the parent tag is considered to have the same .string as its child.**

So:

```
for cell in firstRow:
    if "Total" in cell.string:
        # ...
```

If that doesn't work for you (i.e., there's stuff in the cell you want besides the text in the string) then what you want to do is get all the text in the table cell *before* testing it for "Total":

```
for cell in firstRow:
    text = "".join(cell.find_all(text=True))
    if "Total" in text:
        print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the second one works perfectly fine. I am just trying to also identify if the text came from the cell or the link within the cell. because if it comes from a link within the cell then I need an alert.